# Нужно ли проверять формат и размер файла на стороне сервера при проверке через js на клиенте?

Tags: php, javascript

Нужно ли проверять формат и размер файла на стороне сервера при проверке через js на клиенте? Вряд ли сейчас кто-то отключает js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, нужно. Проверка на стороне клиента - исключительно для удобства клиента и может быть подделана или вовсе отключена.

Comment: Есть золотое правило. "Все что посылает клиент это ложь, ложь и еще раз ложь". Абсолютно все данные обязательно надо проверить и перепроверять.